# Shouldn't meta tags be changed dynamically using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

I store data in meta tags, using flask session.

Then, when I need, I read that data using `getElementById(meta-tag).getAttribute(data)`. If I want to change the data, I could do it using JS, without reloading the page. Everything is fine.

But, now, I have learned that meta-tags must not be changed using js, it should be left to reloading/refreshing of the page...is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

For SEO purpose upto some level it is right, generally search engine and social media crawlers doesn't execute js file. crawlers only read the static contents available on page. So when it crawls the page it might not able to get the meta tags. which can affect in site indexing.

But google crawlers now executes the js. if you have seen it is able to index single page applications like `Angular` apps. But all social media platforms are not doing this.

So it is good to do not make meta tags dynamic and keep it as a static.

Answer (score 1):

I change the meta tags in my applications. Think about SPA's or other content refreshing mechanism. If someone share this page on mobile the right information will be transfered to e.g. whatsapp.

So the reason for me to do that is the shareing usecase.